# Recipient View Only Viewable One Time? createRecipientView

Tags: docusignapi

I am calling createRecipientView and using the response to generate an iFrame in my application.  However, it appears that viewing this iFrame only works one time - subsequent views of the iFrame send the user to the returnUrl.

This is a problem because in my application we maintain documents that the user can sign at their convenience - so they may look at the document and decide to sign it later... which means that we will need to call createRecipientView again and get a new URL for the iFrame.

Am I understanding this correctly?  I can't find much documentation on the URL returned - does it only expire once viewed, or does it expire after a certain amount of time / other conditions?

Comment: Please remember to upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct; the URL will expire either after being used, or after five minutes (token TTL of 300 seconds).

Comment: That is good to know!  If they are filling out the document (eg its a long document), will it still expire?  If so, what is the best way to use Docusign to allow people to fill out long documents on my site?

Comment: There is a "Signer Session timeout" setting that can be changed by DocuSign on the backend and be increased up to 120 minutes maximum. If you're an existing customer I'd suggest reaching out to support to assist. 

If it's just a demo account I'm happy help.

Comment: As long as the recipient is "active" it will not expire.  I believe there's a timeout where if they don't do anything then it will expire, but I believe it's set relatively high (maybe 20 mins) and they would have to be doing absolutely nothing during that time (not even scrolling) for it to expire and you have to generate a new embedded signing link for them.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that an iFrame is not a good idea. Especially if your app will ever be used from a mobile or tablet browser.

I have updated the docs for the [EnvelopeViews: createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) method with information about the one time/limited time use of the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The specification requires an iFrame because the user should be able to click tabs that correspond to different documents/envelopes.  It seems that an iFrame is our only choice?

Also, thanks for updating the docs!

Can you give more information on why using an iFrame should be avoided?

Comment: An iFrame is a bad idea because the DocuSign user interface is designed to use 100% of the screen space. This is especially an issue for mobile signers. And these days, we recommend that you should assume that people will be signing via mobile. Instead of a tabbed interface, why not a modal interface? When the user clicks a button, they are redirected to the right RecipientView. Being able to switch between RecipientViews can easily lead to timeouts when the user neglects to complete the task in a particular tab.